Is a Schengen single entry visa sufficient for a cruise?
I need to confirm that a Schengen single-entry visa will be sufficient for our MSC world europa cruise which stops in Spain, Italy, Malta, and France.

Are all Schengen stops in one sweep or are there non-Schengen stops inbetween?
